# Moving an ImageView according to gravity?

Tags: java, android, sensors, gravity, sensormanager

I am trying to make an ImageView move according to however the user tilts the device.
I'm still learning in Android development so i don't know much about Sensors.
I have tried using this but i'm not sure what to do afterwards but I'm guessing that I'm on the right track.

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
SensorManager mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
Sensor mSensor =  mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY);
```

Any tips would help
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068571/getting-direction-vector-in-android) question for more understanding about gravity.

Try to learn how compass works bye this [example](http://sunil-android.blogspot.in/2013/02/create-our-android-compass.html)

I guess your looking for solution

> ImageView move according to however the user tilts the device

which is exactly look like this [accelerometer example](http://xiangchen.wordpress.com/2011/12/17/an-android-accelerometer-example/)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!
I will try this right away
Another question, is there a way to test this on the Eclipse Emulator? or i would have to try it on an actual phone?

Comment: @user3097181 better try with Device otherwise you need to do this http://code.google.com/p/openintents/wiki/SensorSimulator

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to create and register a `SensorListener`:

```
mSensorManager.registerListener(mSensorListener, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
```

Then in the SensorListener's `onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)` method, get the sensor readings from the `event.values` array.

This will get you the gravity values, which you then use to move the `ImageView`.

As for how to move the `ImageView`, it depends a lot on what sort of `Layout` the view is in, but you could play around with setting the `ImageView's` margins.